# Wikipedia XML Dump, where to get translations for disambiguation directives?

Tags: xml, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates, wikimedia-dumps

In the Wikipedia XML dump articles which are disambiguation include the directive `{{disambiguation}}` somewhere within their content.

This is straightforward for the English wikipedia.
However this directive changes across languages, for example in the Spanish wikipedia an article would contain `{{desambiguación}}`.

I tried querying the wikipedia metadata API. Specifically the one for magicwords:

https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=magicwords&format=json

The list returned include things like : `__DISAMBIGUACION__` and `__DISAMBIG__` but those do not seem to appear in the XML dump.
And `disambiguacion` is certainly not in that list.

Any hints? is there any endpoint or list from where I can get this directive for other languages such as German, Italian.. and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive [{{disambiguation}}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Disambiguation) is **Wikimedia Template** which is used to mark some page as a [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Disambiguation) in the English Wikipedia. This template uses within itself the magic word `__DISAMBIG__` and is connected with the other wikis templates by Wikidata [Item (Q6148868)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6148868). You can access this item by [MediaWiki API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q6148868&props=sitelinks
```

From the result you can see that template for:

- eswiki is **desambiguación**
- dewiki is **begriffsklärung**
- itwiki is **disambigua**
- ruwiki is **неоднозначность**
- fawiki is **ابهام‌زدایی**
- etc...